# REST how to POST or PUT without full entity(@RequestBody)

Tags: java, rest, post, uri, put

I have an Entity 'Vote' that has fields:

```
private Integer id;
private LocalDate date;
private LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
private User user;
private Restaurant restaurant;
```

I know that for REST POST peferably i shoud use resourse pattern like this:

```
/votes
```

and in case of update:

```
/votes/{voteId}
```

Presumably i shoud receive full vote entity in my controller from frontend like this:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Vote> create(@RequestBody Vote vote)
```

But i dont need that to create or update that entity, i only need restaurantId like this:

```
@PostMapping
public void create(@RequestParam int restaurantId) {
        voteService.create(SecurityUtil.getUserId(), restaurantId);
    }
```

So, will be the right choice to use resourse pattern like this, or i'm wrong?

For POST create:

```
/votes?restaurantId=10
```

For PUT update:

```
/votes/{voteId}?restaurantId=10
```

Comment: `PUT /votes/{voteId}?restaurantId=?` to me looks like you update `restaurantId` property of an existing `Vote`. As for other things, I'm not sure what is the question exactly. Can you clarify it a little more?

Comment: I want to create and update a Vote. For example if i use @RequestBody Vote vote, then i shoud sent it's parameters like: private Integer id;
private LocalDate date;
private LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
private User user;
private Restaurant restaurant; But when i creating that entity i don't know anyone of them. This parameters creating on service layer.

Comment: Still don't get it. What does your comment have to do with original question?

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to :

```
@PostMapping
public void create(@RequestParam("restaurantId") int restaurantId) {
    voteService.create(SecurityUtil.getUserId(), restaurantId);
}
```

You should mention the parameter name in @RequestParam("param_name")

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about this.

Comment: With path param URI template would be `/votes/{restaurantId}`, which is the same as `/votes/{voteId}`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using path parameters? It is a bit strange to pass get parameters to POST and PUT.

```
@PostMapping("/{restaurantId}")
public void createPost(@NonNull @PathVariable(value = "restaurantId") String restaurantId) {
    voteService.create(SecurityUtil.getUserId(), restaurantId);
}

@PutMapping("/{restaurantId}")
public void createPut(@NonNull @PathVariable(value = "restaurantId") String restaurantId) {
    voteService.create(SecurityUtil.getUserId(), restaurantId);
}
```

Comment: I am creating a Vote, not Restaurant. I thought i have to use for update example votes/{voteId}?restaurantId=10, and i can't use like this votes/{voteId}/{restaurantId}

Comment: You could go with mixture of the two. 
@PathVariable(value = "restaurantId") and @RequestBody Vote vote

It will make the API cleaner

/votes/<vote-id>/<restaurant_id>

Answer (score 0):

> So, will be the right choice to use resourse pattern like this, or i'm wrong?

"It depends".

The spelling of the URI doesn't matter to the machines; `/0d905ca3-c848-4bc5-bc4a-658fbec88ab5` is a perfectly fine path to use.  Human readable spellings are just a convenience for humans - a "RESTful" spelling like `/votes` isn't any more REST than using the UUID, but when the operators are pouring through logs trying to identify a traffic pattern, they will probably be happier with the second choice.

POST, as a method token, is fine.  See [It's Okay to Use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post) (Fielding, 2009).

`PUT`, however, doesn't quite sound like what you want.  Semantically, [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) means "replace the current representation of the resource with payload of the current message."  It's a *remote authoring* method, which when paired with `GET` gives you a document store:

`PUT` is the method you would use on the world wide web to edit your home page, for example.

```
GET /home-page

(make changes locally)

PUT /home-page
```

And the body of that PUT request is the intended new version of the home page.

In your case:

```
PUT /votes/{voteId}?restaurantId=10
```

is supposed to have a payload that looks like what you would read if you did

```
GET /votes/{voteId}?restaurantId=10
```

It needs to be a complete representation of the resource.

That *doesn't* mean it needs to be a complete representation of the *entity*; resources are a generalization of a document; a *view* into your entity's data.  Remote authoring sends a new representation of the view, and it's the server's job to make the matching changes to the entity.  See [Jim Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).

If you don't want to make your updates that way, that's *fine* -- but then you shouldn't be using `PUT`, as that defeats the point of having a common semantic with all other resources (you should use POST).

Answer (score 0):

I understand, that author doesn't need answer for that particular case already, but question is common, so **this answer is general recomendation if you come here from google with simmilar situatiuon.**

If you don't want to pass entity (Vote) on creation, you can pass DTO.
In fact, you should past DTO in most cases as at least ID usually is generated by app. And it's totally ok if that DTO has single param as in this case.
If you don't want to create separate class for that DTO, you can create inner static class, or `record` if yours codebase is java 17+. So it'll look like this:

```
    @PostMapping
    public void create(@RequestBody CreateVoteDto createVoteDto) {
        voteService.create(SecurityUtil.getUserId(), createVoteDto.restaurantId());
    }
    record CreateVoteDto(long restaurantId) {}
```

You can also receive a Map, but I prefer a record because it's more explicit and therefore less error-prone than getting it via string.

```
    @PostMapping
    public void create(@RequestBody Map<String, Long> body) {
        voteService.create(SecurityUtil.getUserId(), body.get("restaurantId"));
    }
```